# JavaScript Click Boolean to select and unselect svg element.

Tags: javascript, d3.js, onmouseclick

I have multiple svg elements that I want to select to highlight. When I click the first time, I want the plot to highlight. When I click anywhere else on the page, I want to unselect. When I click another element while one is already selected. I want to unselect.
I am having trouble determining if a mouse click is somewhere not on a selectable element. How would I set up an event listener to determine if I am selecting somewhere on the page that is not an element?

Right now my event listener on the document looks like this:

```
   document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    console.log(event.relatedTarget);
});
```

An help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: add event handlers to the elements you want to select, if the doc event handler is called it is not a click on these elements

Comment: @rioV8 thanks for the reply! I am using d3.on('click', function(){}) for my event handler. The event listener picks up when there is an event but I am not sure how to send the element information to the event listener?

Comment: select the element and attach an on-click handler